# pdfkit (for python) - scale output to fit in single A4 pdf page

Tags: python, html, formatting, converters, pdfkit

I'm using pdfkit Python libraries to convert an html page to pdf.

All I'm doing is using the command:

```
pdfkit.from_file('mypage.html', 'output.pdf')
```

The problem is that I obtain a multiple-page pdf, whereas I'd like to have everything on one page. How can I force pdfkit to shrink/scale the web page to fit on a regular A4 page?
The webpage is locally saved on my PC, so I could also act on the html, if needed. Is there a way to "rescale" a web page at once?

Thank you!

Comment: It's a shame this hasn't been answered. As an alternative, I'd like page size to be scaled to fit into 1 page (rather than shrinking content).